# how can we derive both the CDF of $M$ and the PDF of $M$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given $X_i \sim \operatorname{Uniform}[0, 1]$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$.
What is the distribution of $M := \min(X_1, \dots, X_n)$?

I feel like I'm missing something and I've been stuck on this for two days

Comment: $F_M(x) = 1-P(M \geq x) = 1-P(X_1 \geq x)^n$, that is your CDF. Differentiate it to get the PDF.

Comment: This other question walks through some of the details that you might find useful:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460727/mean-and-variance-of-first-order-statistic-from-a-uniform-distribution-minx .  I hope this helps.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-random-variables-distributed

Answer (score 1):

I guess the $X_i$'s are iid.  Let $0 \leq m \leq 1$

$$F(m)=P(M \leq m)=1-P( M>m)=1-P(X_1>m,X_2>m,...,X_n>m)$$
because if the minimum of the $X_i$'s are greater than $m$, then all of them are greater than $m$, and reciprocally.
Use the independence property and the fact that the $X_i's$ have the same distribution
$$P(X_1>m,X_2>m,...,X_n>m)=\prod_{i=1}^nP(X_i>m)=P(X_1>m)^n$$

We have $P(X_1>m)=(1-m)$

Therefore,
$$F(m)=P(M \leq m)=1-(1-m)^n$$
if $m>1$, then $F(m)=1$
if $m<0$, then $F(m)=0$

The cdf is then $$F'(m)=m(1-m)^{n-1}$$

Comment: can you explain this a bit more to me please ?

Comment: which part needs more details?